# Why Don't The Children Recive The Signal

Tags: c, signals, system-calls

I have a parent process that is spawning X number of child processes (player) based off the first argument passed to the program. After each child is spawned it sends them a signal. For now all I want the children to do it print they received the signal and exit, but they don't seem to get the signal from the parent. Are the children not getting the signal or am I handling it wrong?

Parent:

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void reciveCard() {
        write(1, "signal recived\n", 15);
        exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        int numPlayers, i;
        int *kpids;

        numPlayers = atoi(argv[1]);

        kpids = malloc(numPlayers * sizeof(int));

        signal(SIGUSR1, SIG_IGN);
        for(i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
                if((kpids[i] = fork()) == 0) {
                        if(execlp("./player\0", "./player\0", (char *) NULL) == -1) {
                                printf("error\n");
                                exit(1);
                        }
                }
        }

        for(i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
                printf("%d\n", kpids[i]);
                kill(kpids[i], SIGUSR1);
        }

        wait(NULL);
        return 0;
}
```

Child:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void reciveCard() {
        write(1, "signal recived\n", 15);
        exit(0);
}
int main() {

        signal(SIGUSR1, reciveCard);
        while(1) {
                sleep(1);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is unclear why you include the code for `receiveCard()` in the parent. Also, there is an obvious race condition here.

Comment: I'd seen an example where the handler was included in the parent as well and wasn't sure if that was my issue. I forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a race condition.

The parent program does the `fork` calls so *fast* that it falls into the `kill` loop *before* any child has a chance to do the `execlp`.

Thus, the child can't set up the handler fast enough. That is, when the signal comes in, the child is still ignoring it because of the parent's `SIG_IGN` call that it has inherited.

Now, after the `execlp`, the child will set up the handler, but the signal has *already* occurred, so the the handler will *never* be called.

To see this, add a `sleep(1)` between the two parent loops and it should work.

Comment: @EOF I think that I covered that in the 2nd sentence with: _falls into the `kill` loop before any child has a chance to do the `execlp`_

Comment: I still think this answer is a bit unclear. I'd point out that the race window starts at the `fork()` in the parent and ends with the `signal()` in the child. Notably, it *doesn't* end with the `execlp()`.